# masking kernel density map by study region in rhr

Tags: raster, kernel-density

I have rhr-produced kernel density estimation of several marine species at the global scale. I want to mask these maps by the world map. However the resulting map is weird since latitude and logitude ranges are not same as a coordinate system.
An example output is same as below:
[A kernel density map produced by rhr package, masked by global marine areas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0WfN.png)

Comment: That output looks fine

Comment: You're right, but It seems that the extent of the window is based on the kernel out map, is there any way to define the extent of the masked output based on the mask feature (in my case, global ocean and seas border)?

Comment: No, but see `?extend`  in raster / terra

Comment: I realized that I have to incorporate the impassable barriers (lands) into KDE. This is more reliable way than masking the output kde raster by study area. I found GME in ArcGIS, but it dos not works for ArcGIS 10.4 and newer. Is there any idea?

Comment: That is not related. You can ask another question, but please provide a minimal, self-contained, reproducible example.